# Does @SpringBootTest scan bean configuration test package if has same name?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test, component-scan

Above is codes in main.kolitn.~~

```kotlin
package com.example.demo   // in main folder

@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)
}

@Configuration("show")
class Show {

    init {
        System.err.println("[main] this is Test#init")
    }

    @Bean("map")
    fun map(): Map<Int, Int> {
        System.err.println("[main] testMap bean loaded...")
        return mapOf(10 to 11, 12 to 13)
    }
}
```

and this is codes in test.kotlin.~~~

```kotlin
package com.example.demo     // in test folder

@SpringBootTest
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var map: Map<Int, Int>

    @Test
    fun contextLoads() {
        System.err.println("this is test")
        System.err.println("[test] map : $map")
    }
}

//@Configuration("test")
open class Show {

    init {
        System.err.println("[test] this is Test#init")
    }

    @Bean("map")
    fun map(): Map<Int, Int> {
        System.err.println("[test] map bean loaded...")
        return mapOf(1 to 2, 3 to 4)
    }
}
```

when I run the `DeomoApplicaitonTests#contextLoads()`, I expected Show class in main folder is scanned and `[main] brabra` logs will be printed in console because Show class in test folder. But actual output is

```
[test] this is Show#init
[test] map bean loaded...
this is test
[test] map : {1=2, 3=4}
```

I don't understand why Show class in test folder was scanned even that doesn't have `@Configuration` annotation. Is there any document to explain this? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring, the `@SpringBootTest` annotation generally scans for beans in the main application package and its sub-packages. Since your test class `DemoApplicationTests` is in a different package (`test`), it won't automatically scan the `Show` class in the main folder.

However, the `@SpringBootTest` annotation also loads the entire application context, which means it scans for beans in your entire project. The `Show` class in the test folder is being picked up because it has the same name as the `Show` class in the main folder, and Spring is probably merging or overriding the beans during context loading.

To control which configuration class is loaded during the test, you can use the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation on your test class and specify the configuration class you want to use explicitly.

Here's an example:

```kotlin
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [Show::class]) // Specify the configuration class to load
class DemoApplicationTests {
    // ...
}
```

This should ensure that only the `Show` class from the main folder is considered during the test, and you should see the expected logs.